# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, babeljs

I am a beginner in React,Not able to debug the error

This is my code using components in React.

I am trying to simulate a google Search Image result with Image,caption and Link, but on the browser all I see is an empty screen.

The error statement is :

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Object.I.render (react-dom.production.min.js:238)
    at <anonymous>:99:10
    at n (babel.min.js:12)
    at r (babel.min.js:12)
    at o (babel.min.js:12)
    at u (babel.min.js:12)
    at E (babel.min.js:1)
```

The error doesn't specify which line or anything. and the link says

> The full text of the error you just encountered is:
> *Target container is not a DOM element.*

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id = "container"></div>
            <script type = "text/babel">
                var destination = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    
                class ResImg extends React.Component{
                    render(){
                        return(
                            <img src = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.insider.com%2Fthe-batman-2021-movie-details-information-2020-2&psig=AOvVaw0AeAaWCyxcHCYi3PRMc6VS&ust=1601364735924000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJi85taqi-wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"></img>
                        )
                    }
                }
    
                class ResCaption extends React.Component{
                    render(){
                        return(
                            <p>Batman 2021</p>
                        )
                    }
                }
    
                class ResLink extends React.Component{
                    render(){
                        return(
                            <a href = "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.insider.com%2Fthe-batman-2021-movie-details-information-2020-2&psig=AOvVaw0AeAaWCyxcHCYi3PRMc6VS&ust=1601364735924000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJi85taqi-wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD"></a>
                        )
                    }
                }
    
                class SearchRes extends React.Component{
                    render(){
                        return(
                            <div>
                                <ResImg/>
                                <ResCaption/>
                                <ResLink/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
    
                ReactDOM.render(
                    <SearchRes/>,destination
                )
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: have you tried to *use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings*

Comment: should i download the non-minified dev env?

Comment: I don't know that message means, I just wondered if you had followed the advice given in the error message - does `Target container is not a DOM element.` mean anything to you?

Comment: Voting to close as `typo-type` question.

Comment: 1. You need `document.getElementById("container")` 2. HAD the container had a class, your would have needed `var destination = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];`  because it returns a collection. 3. HAD it had a class and you wanted the first, then you should use `var destination = document.querySelector(".container");` instead.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is much easier to help you if you post a [mcve] but first make appropriate effort to find the issue yourself

Comment: @mplungjan i dont post here unless I dont find a solution on google.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever you see such an error you can visit the page it suggests to see the full error. So, when opening https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 , you can see that

`Target container is not a DOM element`,

meaning that you try to render your app into a wrong dom node. The problem is here:

`var destination = document.getElementsByClassName("container");`,

you need to use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 4):

If anyone who has the error and is using `document.getElementById`, you need to have a component inside. So instead of:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    Hi!
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Replace the "Hi!" string with a new component which displays the string:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NewComponent></NewComponent>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Where the new component is this one:

```
export const NewComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>Hi!</div>
  );
}
```

If you still have the errors, maybe try the solutions from [this](https://medium.com/@kumara_suresh25/i-got-below-error-ba3bc059ee59) and [this](https://iqcode.com/code/javascript/minified-react-error-200), they worked for me

And if your css doesn't work, don't forget to move the .css inside the public folder, and add the  tag to your .html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./App2.css" />
    <title>My Extension</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change this

```
var destination = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
```

to

```
var destination = document.getElementById("container");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is in your code you are trying this

```
   var destination = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
```

it return array of elements
where what you have to do it to use it like this

```
   var destination = document.getElementById("container");
```

as you are using id="container" so you have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me because I placed the `<div id='root'></div>` below a `<script></script>` tag and this `<script>` took some time to load as a result react was not able to find an element with `#root` during render.